# Spaces in filepath

Tags: powershell, csv, escaping

Working on a simple script to pull workstation names from a `.csv` file then open a folder location on that workstation. I keep running into trouble on how to get PowerShell to not split the filepath. So far I have tried:

Single quotes: `'\\$results\c$\direc\Desktop\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'`

Regular quotation: `"\\$results\c$\direc\Desktop\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`

Double quotes: `""\\$results\c$\direc\Desktop\Start Menu\Programs\Startup""`

Backtick in front of the space: `` "\\$results\c$\direc\Desktop\Start` Menu\Programs\Startup" ``

8.3 name: `"\\$results\c$\direc\Deskto~1\StartM~1\Progra~1\Startu~1"`

Here is my code:

```
$inputFile = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\workstations.csv"
$results = @()
Import-CSV -Path $inputFile -Header Workstations | % {
  Invoke-Item -Path "\\$results\c$\JHMCIS\Desktop\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
}
```

Everything works perfect until it reads the file path. It then kicks back an error that says the path does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string formatting is fine, the problem is that you just created an empty array named `$results` and then are adding that to the string when you do your invoke.  change your last line to

`% {Invoke-Item -Path "\\$($_.Workstations)\c$\JHMCIS\Desktop\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"}`

Note that the above assumes that the file has no headings and only a single column that you are defining the name of using the `-header` param on your `Import-CSV`

Comment: god, i didn't even notice he was using empty variable there xD

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I thought the array was needed for pulling the workstation names out of the file.